Understanding multiple consecutive await statements
I was playing around with the ContinueWith function and I ended up not understanding it.
In this example code:
var s = Task.FromResult(true).ContinueWith(async t => t).ContinueWith(async t => t);
await await await await await s;

What does each of the "awaits" await?

Don't mix async/await and ContinueWith: ContinueWith predates async/await. It's very complicated once you scratch the surface (so it can be quite hard to reason about what it's doing), and there's almost nothing which ContinueWith can do which cannot be expressed more simply and obviously with async/await

Nothing awaits anything because the first tasks is created in the Completed state and so are all other tasks. All this does is wrap one task in another, nothing more. I bet you even have compiler warnings saying that t isn't awaited. The await line unwraps the tasks. It's equivalent to await( await( await( await( await s))));

"I was playing around with the "ContinueWith" function and I ended up not understanding it." - I happen to have "jumped over" it from the "BeginXXX - EndXXX"-Async days to async/await and I haven't missed it or have had to use it, yet. So, if not just out of curiosity, dealing with legacy code or academic purposes, I assume it is quite safe to ignore :)

I bet this was an failed interview question. ;)

@PanagiotisKanavos the continuations are invoked on the ThreadPool (unless there is an ambient non-default TaskScheduler), so I wouldn't expect that all tasks are completed.

Let's answer in a very naive manner first:
var s = Task.FromResult(true).ContinueWith(async t => t ).ContinueWith(async t => t);
await await await await await s;

First, let's just split the expression into its constituent parts:
var s1 = Task.FromResult(true);
var s2 = s1.ContinueWith(async t => t );
var s3 = s2.ContinueWith(async t => t);

if we expand the two first var declarations with full type, we get this:
Task<bool> s1 = Task.FromResult(true);
Task<Task<Task<bool>>> s2 = s1.ContinueWith(async t => t );

The first is simple, it is a task that will yield a boolean value. The next need some explanation.
When you do task.ContinueWith(...), you have an overload that takes in the task that was preceeding the ... part, in this case, the task reference. This task gets passed into the continuation method, so this:
s1.ContinueWith(async t => t)

means that s1 will be passed into the async t => t continuation as t, and then it will be returned.
Additionally, when you do:
var x = task.ContinueWith(...)

you get back a task that can be awaited, to get the return value from .... In this case it is another task because you just returned the task that was passed in.
So this means that this expression:
var s2 = s1.ContinueWith(async t => t );

will actually return a task, from ContinueWith, and this task wraps another task, from t => t. So you can await the task from ContinueWith to get the s1 task, which can also be awaited.
Let's expand the expressions fully:
Task<bool> s1 = Task.FromResult(true);
Task<Task<Task<bool>>> s2 = s1.ContinueWith(async t => t );
Task<Task<Task<Task<Task<bool>>>>> s = s2.ContinueWith(async t => t);

each level adds another "task that wraps another task that wraps ...".
When we unwrap the 5-level await, we get this:

first we await the final ContinueWith
this produces a task, from async t = t, so we await this
this produces a task, the first ContinueWith, so we await this
this produces a task, the first async t = t, so we await this
this produces a task, the original Task.FromResult(true)

so the final code can be looked at like this:
var s = Task.FromResult(true).ContinueWith(async t => t ).ContinueWith(async t => t);
                    ^                ^         ^                ^             ^
                    |                |         |                |             |
                await       await  await       |    await    await s;         |
                                |              |      |                       |
                                +--------------+      +-----------------------+

Note that all this happens synchronously, there is no waiting, no async code at all here. This is because all the tasks involved complete inline immediately, producing their results.
In general, ContinueWith is something best left for framework and library authors, and not really a construct we're meant to be using any more. There are many things you need to be aware of, in particular around exception handling, that async/await just does naturally for you without hassle.

You're doing something weird, and you're getting weird output.
Let's make it a little simpler:
var s = Task.FromResult(true).ContinueWith(t => t);
await await s;


Task.FromResult(true) returns a Task<bool>
ContinueWith is passed that Task<bool> when it completes: the idea is that it can query the task to see whether it has succeeded / failed, and get its result.
The general idea is that ContinueWith returns a value, not a Task. However, you're returning t from it, which is the Task<bool>. ContinueWith wraps that return value in a Task, the idea being that that Task completes once the Task.FromResult(true) completes and the continuation has run. That gives you a Task<Task<bool>>.

This isn't that unusual, which is why Task.Unwrap() exists.
When you make the continuation take an async t => t, you're telling the compiler to generate a delegate which returns a Task<T>. In this case, it's a method which takes a Task<bool> and returns a Task<Task<bool>>.
Note that this is not usual. You wouldn't normally write something like this:
async Task<Task<bool>> Foo()
{
    await ...;
    return Task.FromResult(true);
}

If you've got an async Task-returning method, you'd just return a value, not another Task.
Then the continuation wraps this in another task to get a Task<Task<Task<bool>>>.
Then you do the same with a second continuation, and get even more tasks.
You could tease it all out and work out what each Task represents, but there's not really much point: you're doing something silly, and you're getting silly results.
Remember that ContinueWith predates async/await: you're not really supposed to mix the two (in fact, you're not really supposed to use ContinueWith at all these days).

This is interesting to me in a few ways. Thank you for writing out how 5 Tasks are created, I wasn't aware of it. But then you are saying that ContinueWith is not supposed to be mixed with async/await. This surprises me, since I have never read about it anywhere.

C# 4 introduced the TPL and ContinueWith, and that was such a headache that C# 5 introduced async/await. I doubt there are many docs which explicitly say "async/await supersedes ContinueWith", but that's what happened in practice. And that's a good thing: just read through the options you can pass ContinueWith, and pretend you can predict what will happen for a chain of ContinueWiths all with different options.

... equivalent code written using async/await will use control flow mechanisms you're already familiar with (methods, try/catch, etc), and it will be much more obvious what it's doing

Just to further extend/illustrate canton7's point.
If you do one operation at a time (instead of chaining them) then it should be easier to understand why do you need 5 awaits:
Task<bool> t1 = Task.FromResult(true);
Task<Task<Task<bool>>> t2 = t1.ContinueWith(async t => t);
Task<Task<Task<Task<Task<bool>>>>> t3 = t2.ContinueWith(async t => t);
    
Task<Task<Task<Task<bool>>>> r1 = await t3;
Task<Task<Task<bool>>> r2 = await r1;
Task<Task<bool>> r3 = await r2;
Task<bool> r4 = await r3;
bool r = await r4; 


With an UnWrap call on the the ContinueWith, the number of required awaits is three
Task<bool> t1 = Task.FromResult(true);
Task<Task<bool>> t2 = t1.ContinueWith(async t => t).Unwrap();
Task<Task<Task<bool>>> t3 = t2.ContinueWith(async t => t).Unwrap();
    
Task<Task<bool>> r1 = await t3;
Task<bool> r2 = await r1;
bool r = await r2;

